# Is there a bug on StackExchange?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, top-bar, notifications

My Unix.StackExchange and my Stackoverflow are not updating correctly, I got some points, but they don't show up on my achievements tab. The tab "Your Communities" is also not updating correctly. The new points have been added to my points by the side of my picture but when I click the "StackExchange" button it hasn't updated that.

I can see the new points in "Reputation" info.

I tried to refresh the browser and I also tried to restart the browser.

Comment: I've noticed that I'm having to dismiss notifications on both the mobile app and the site...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had problems with a datacenter test that left our caching layer in a partially broken state.

All issues should now be resolved.

See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, there is! And:

[image]

More information:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268957/792066
- [Reputation and inbox notification shows up again after refresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238155/213575)